# How to Seed created Laravel Field

Tags: laravel, migration, seed

Hello Everyone I have a question:  I am a new lo Laravel and I'm wondering is there is a way to seed a newly created column?
I created a new column using migration command:

> php artisan migration:make --table Authors

I created a new field image, now I want to populate it with [www.thispersondoesntexists.com](http://www.thispersondoesntexists.com) images. Is there a way to do that for every existing record in my database?

Comment: you have to write a seeder for that purpose, or you can set as default one image

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the following fields in your seeders file which is located in database -> seeders -> DatabaseSeeder.

DB::table('users')->insert([
    'name' => Str::random(10),
    'email' => Str::random(10).'@gmail.com',
    'password' => Hash::make('password'),
]);

here add your table name and table fields.Then use the following command.
php artisan make:seeder DatabaseSeeder
```